# Flutter change Drawer state using RiverPod State management

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, riverpod

by using `RiverPod` State management, which i try to work on self improvment to learn and how can i use that i made a simple project and i'm trying to open `Drawer` by pressing on icon in `AppBar` which that's on another class and file, unfortunately doing like with `RiverPod` sample code my code doesn't work correctly and main class don't trigger on clicking on icon

simply i want to open drawer by clicking icon on `AppBar`

main file:

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Riverpod Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final drawerState = StateNotifierProvider<DrawerVisibility>((_)=>DrawerVisibility());
    return Consumer(
      builder: (context, read, _) {
        final state = read(drawerState.state);
        print('CLICKED $state');
        if(state){
          _scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer();
        }
        return Scaffold(
          key: _scaffoldKey,
          appBar: MyAppBar(),
          drawer: Drawer(),
          body: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'You have pushed the button this many times:',
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

`AppBar` class file content:

```dart
class MyAppBar extends StatelessWidget with PreferredSizeWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final drawerState = StateNotifierProvider<DrawerVisibility>((_)=>DrawerVisibility());
    return AppBar(
      automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      title: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.menu), onPressed: () {
            context.read(drawerState).changeDrawerState();
          }),
          Text('My Sample'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight);
}
```

and finally `RiverPod` class

```dart
class DrawerVisibility extends StateNotifier {
  DrawerVisibility() : super(false);

  void changeDrawerState() => state = true;
}
```

another issue is when i start application in first time i get this output:

```
I/flutter (12240): CLICKED false
I/flutter (12240): CLICKED false
```

without any click on icon

Answer (score 2):

instead of `Consumer` you should try using `ProviderListener`, its better when you want to show dialogs, snackbars, push/pop, or in this case opening a drawer. Finally instead of creating a final provider inside each build method, just create it once as a final global parameter so in each widget you read/watch it it uses the same instance

```
/// Create a final global StateNotifierProvider in your file instead of one inside each widget
final drawerState = StateNotifierProvider<DrawerVisibility>((_)=>DrawerVisibility());

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ProviderListener<bool>(
      onChange: (context, state) {
        if(state) _scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer();
        //maybe check if the _scaffoldKey is mounted or is the drawer open before doing something
      },
      provider: drawerState.state,
      child: Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        appBar: MyAppBar(),
        drawer: Drawer(),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'You have pushed the button this many times:',
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And in `MyAppBar` delete the drawerState so it uses the same global that your `HomePage`, also when closing the drawer at some point you should make the state false again